# Split arbitrary number of words into two columns - Google Sheets

Tags: split, google-sheets

tl;dr

How can I split an arbitrary number of words into only two columns, always with just the last word in the last column and all other words in the first column?

```
=IFS(
LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""))=1,
 SPLIT(C2," "),
LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""))=2,
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","%",2),"%"))
LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""))=3,
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","%",3),"%"))   
)
```

Och, aye, laddies! I'm in a wee spare bit o' bother, an' I need yer help. I've ta take the mottos o' **ALL** the Scots clans, and t' break 'em oot inta columns in this parcel of codes called Google Sheets. Tak ye a few examples:

- SERVA JUGUM
- PER ARDUA AD ALTA
- THROUGH
- DIEU POUR NOUS

**HOWEVER**, for some daft reason, I've to put them into **NAE MORE** than two columns, with the last word comin' alone in the last column.

- SERVA | JUGUM
- PER ARDUA AD | ALTA
- THROUGH
- DIEU POUR | NOUS

I've tried everythin' I cae think on - QUERY, LEN, SUBSTITUTE, SPLIT, SPIT, naught seems t' work. The code above will pull out the first word(s) in the first column all right an' tight, but it will nae **expand** as SPLIT is wont t' do.

I'm sure there's a barrel o' answers for `R` and what have ye...but how do ye do this in Google Sheets (aye, I need her in Sheets)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*?) {0,1}(\w+)$")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))),"")
```